# Excel VBA-Using VBIDE.CodeModule to create dynamic variable names closes userform and will not reload?

Tags: vba, excel

Used this code successfully to create range of dynamically constructed variable names. Works really well but unfortunately it closes the calling userform unless the userform is loaded modally (but it needs to be opened modelessly so user can also access the sheet) and no amount of reloading the form works in actually reloading the form.

Have tried hiding and unloading the form and then reloading it modelessly but it doesnt reload.

[Excel VBA: Dynamic Variable Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266005/6063812)

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SourceQueryString As String = "myValue1=Dave&someOtherValue=Hockey&HockeyDate=Yesterday"


Sub Test()

Dim queryStringVariablesComponent As VBIDE.vbComponent
Dim queryStringVariablesModule As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim codeText As String
Dim lineNum As Long: lineNum = 1
Dim lineCount As Long

Set queryStringVariablesComponent = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("QueryStringVariables")
Set queryStringVariablesModule = queryStringVariablesComponent.CodeModule
queryStringVariablesModule.DeleteLines 1, queryStringVariablesModule.CountOfLines

Dim parts
parts = Split(SourceQueryString, "&")

Dim part, variableName, variableValue
For Each part In parts
    variableName = Split(part, "=")(0)
    variableValue = Split(part, "=")(1)

    codeText = "Public Property Get " & variableName & "() As String"
    queryStringVariablesModule.InsertLines lineNum, codeText
    lineNum = lineNum + 1

    codeText = variableName & " = """ & variableValue & ""
    queryStringVariablesModule.InsertLines lineNum, codeText
    lineNum = lineNum + 1

    codeText = "End Property"
    queryStringVariablesModule.InsertLines lineNum, codeText
    lineNum = lineNum + 1

Next

DisplayIt
End Sub

Sub DisplayIt()
    MsgBox myValue1 'Should output "Dave"
End Sub
```

> Row 2 - Column header fields which differ according to user selected header used to construct variable names

[image]

> Final Solution

[image]

---

### Updated final solution

> *Scoping names to sheet (sheet("H"), rather than workbook, so that they can be referenced for deletion.*

[image]

### Names Creation

```
For Each HeaderCell In HeaderRange

    HeaderName = Replace(HeaderCell.value, " ", "_")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("H").Names.Add Name:=HeaderName, RefersTo:=HeaderCell

Next
```

### Names Deletion

```
For Each nName In Names

    If nName.Parent.Name = "H" Then nName.Delete

Next nName
```

### Names Range referencing

> Only slight annoyance is because the names are scoped to sheet rather than to workbook, the need to have to include a reference to the sheet whenever the range is used  - Range("H!A_TEAM").
>
> But scoping the Names to a dedicated sheet is the only way I can see to identify them for deletion without deleting all the names ranges where the other ones are permanent.

```
Range("H!A_TEAM").Column
```

Comment: (We must have different definitions of "success"!)  What you are attempting is tricky and bound to be fraught with problems, and I can almost guarantee there's an alternate solution to "whatever" it is that you feel makes it necessary to change variable names at run-time. Could you explain the "end goal" of your project and the problem, what you're trying to accomplish? (I suspect this is an "[*XY Problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)" (basically, asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.)

Comment: I looked over the source you linked; Note that, even in that question, the answer you're copying from is neither the accepted answer, nor the highest rated.  Perhaps the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266400/8112776) on that question would better for you (using a collection instead of messing with variable names at runtime.) Here's an excellent guide to [**VBA Collections**](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/).

Comment: See above Ashleedawg - images added for clarity.

Without knowing which headers to expect, I want to be able to cleanly create a dynamic generic look up where I know what form the variable names comprise and can easily locate the headers and their addresses.
 
Creating collections or a dictionary object as you suggest is pointless duplication since a range on the sheet already containing the column headers is in a way a kind of collection or array.

Besides doing it like that would mean I would have to cycle through the collection every time to find the header/cell address

Comment: This way there is no repeated cycling or looping through an array or collection to find the header and it's address. It is just here boom straight away with one complete left to right scan of row 2 range. But as I say it's interfering with the calling form and closing it somehow unless as I say opened modelessly which prevents needed access to the sheet and attempting to reopen it or change it to modal after creation of dynamic variables is failing.

Comment: Still a little unclear so I want to confirm: Do you just need to find the correct column dynamically based on the column heading in the first row?  if so, that can be done easily with a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`, either as worksheet functions, or in VBA with `Application.WorksheetFunction...`.  Named Ranges is another way to do something like this.  Or, an array with the names and cell addresses.  There are several other ways to accomplish that (but my preference would be `Index`/`Match`.

Comment: Row 2 - I need to find each header column address in row 2.

These headers in row 2 can be different depending on what option the user selects - in total there are maybe 100 different headers in a background reference sheet which are copied over in various permutations to this main sheet depending on user choice.

The headers might be the same, different, or some same some different & no necessarily in same order.

The way I had started doing it so far is just with by clobbering the whole header row with a series of .finds working through each / every possible header code eg "FT A ODDS".

Comment: Yes that's as you would do it. But it's rather a crude and cumbersome way of doing it IMO and this way I find far more neat and efficient personally. However, unless I can resolve the userform display impact I might just have to resign myself to repeated worksheet.find methods sadly.

Comment: You only need to scan the row once in order to build a dictionary lookup or similar. Once it's built you can store it in a global variable.

Comment: Yes and then another 100 or so scans (or however many headers there are) each looping through the dictionary to locate each header cell / header address.

Comment: Don't knock it until you've tried it.  Unless you're doing millions of lookups the performance impact will be pretty much unmeasureable.  The whole point of a dictionary is a no-loop super-fast lookup.

Comment: I'm not knocking it per se. As I say it's kinda what I have been doing except at a worksheet range level rather than collection level.

It's just less clean and efficient that's all. 

Why run all round the neighbourhood checking house to house when you can just go straight to a known address directly.

Comment: @user6063812 "Crude and cumbersome" would be more like the your original request - ignoring Excel's built-in features to programmatically manipulate variable names at runtime... that's going to cause you problems, if you get it working at all.  Excel is made for loops and however complex you think your workbook is, is nothing compared to Excel's capabilities.  I think you have it backwards: your method is the round-about way; using the appropriate built-in functionality (not `Find`, I didn't suggest that one) is the fast, clean, direct, efficient, and *supported* method. Good luck.

Comment: @ashleedawg You already commented in the OP comment that you "agree this is a great answer in theory, and a "neat trick'"

I concur. Match, Find, whatever, it's all worksheet range level searches. As you say this is a 'neat trick' that cut's out the need for all these searches and loops. However, I may need to resign myself to more orthodox supported methods - maybe apart from it's neatness it has other unforeseen effects that I am experiencing.

Thanks for comments anyway (Y)

Comment: With dynamic code there's also the question of how to get your project to compile with calls to functions which aren't created until run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to reopen a Userform as Modeless after modifying a Module's code.

The issue that you are have stems from using the Userform's Default Instance.  It would be best to write a subroutine ("Sub ShowUserform()" to create an instance of the Userform.

> ```
>  Sub ShowUserform()
>       Dim MyUserForm1 As New UserForm1
>       UserForm1.Show False
>   End Sub
> ```

Adding ↓this code↓ to the the last line of code that updates the `QueryStringVariables` module will re-show the Userform Modeless after 1 second.

> ```
>  Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "ShowUserform"
> ```

Alternately, you could `Unload` the Default Instance before showing it again.

> ```
> Unload UserForm1
> UserForm1.Show
> ```

Comment: thank you very much - you've covered both aspects of my situation comprehensively very well.

With the form reload, the Unload / Show doesnt work ie bring back the form but the time delay method does work and bring back the form.

I need to remember user selections on the form and then reset them to as they were and the 1 second blip is a little bit sorta inelegant if I am being pedantic but it definitely does the job.

It seems it's the creating of the dynamic code that somehow knocks out the userform and somehow temporarily prevents it from reloading.

Comment: I am continuing with the form reload method for now but I am won over by the dictionary way as well so might opt for that in the end.

There would be no userform blip but at the same time these dynamically created variables are so cool!

Comment: Lol..dynamically create variables are very cool.  Alternately, with a couple of helper functions you could get the same results from adding defined names to the workbook or worksheets.

Comment: you're very welcome - I would tick it a dozen times if I could lol. Do you mean dynamically creating named range to a worksheet with cell addresses stored as an example of a dynamically referenceable variable and value pair, or something else? 

Funnily enough I have worked with dynamic named ranges quite a bit in this project but it never occurred to me to use them as dynamic variables - doh!

In a way they would be better because I wouldn't have the slightly inelegant userform unload / reload / time delay & then wouldnt have to mess around remembering userform reload selections.

Comment: please see above final solution - as proposed by you - I think names ranges is best solution!! Wonderful - love dynamic variables lol!

Comment: Very cool. Why are you storing the Range.Address and not a Range reference?

Comment: Hi TinMan! See updated complete solution. I think maybe changing it in line with your question - if I understand you correctly? Only issue, as stated above, is the annoying need to have to include the sheet prefix whenever using the named range - but unless you can show me a neater way to refer to these ranges I am probably just being a bit pedantic. Thanks pal - very helpful indeed. (Y)

Comment: Using `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=HeaderName, RefersTo:=HeaderCell` will add the range to the  `ThisWorkbook.Names` collection.  In this way, you will be able to refer to the named range anywhere in the Workbook (e.g. `Range("H_TQ_Odds")` of  `Range("H_TQ_Odds").Offset(1)`) .

Comment: Alternatively, ` HeaderCell.Name = Replace(HeaderCell.Value, " ", "_")` will add the name to the Workbook Names collection.

Comment: The issue is TinMan, is that I need some way of identifying these dynamically created ranges so that I can delete and recreate them upon user action. And I don't know how to identify them (and not other ranges that should not be deleted) except through sheet parent - hence the reason for scoping them to a dedicated sheet ("H"). Unless there's some other way of identifying them IDK?

Comment: The ranges will still be scoped to the worksheet  but their names will be scoped to the workbook.  Run this in the immediate window `Sheet1.Range("A1").Name = "Test":Sheet2.Select:?Range("Test").Parent.Name
`

Comment: Yes thanks - tried that but the only concern here is that the parent sheet is the main sheet and using that parameter as the name identifier would mean I would be prevented from adding any further named ranges to this sheet that I wanted to keep and not delete. However, to get round this I have added the visible parameter setting it to false. So just to be sure if I do happen to need any further named ranges in that same parent sheet then I can create them with visible=true and only delete names in that main sheet where visible=false. Good job - thanks again. Wonderful help.

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=HeaderName, RefersTo:=HeaderCell, Visible:=False

Comment: For Each nName In Names
    If Range(nName.Name).Parent.Name = "SharbonSheet" And nName.Visible = False Then nName.Delete
Next nName

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174839/discussion-between-tinman-and-user6063812).

Comment: The worksheet and workbook names are mutually independent  collections.  The only thing that the visibility property does is determine whether or not the name is visible in the Names Manager

Answer (score 1):

I will address the the OP's question which seems to be "How to create a Modeless Userform at runtime" later tonight. Right now I want to clear up this misconception about using a Dictionary to return a Cell reference versus using `Range()` or `Cells()` to return the reference.

OP Comment

> As I say it's kinda what I have been doing except at a worksheet range level rather than collection level. It's just less clean and efficient that's all. Why run all round the neighbourhood checking house to house when you can just **go straight to a known address directly**.

Cells and Range Objects store references to the cells in a VBA Collection which can be looked up by their cell address.  A Dictionary can also store a collection of references to cell objects which can be looked up by their cell address.

So if Cells, Ranges, a VBA Collection and a Dictionary are all collections which is the fastest?  Here are the results of looking up 1000 cells 1000 times using the code below:

[image]

Notice that the Dictionary was by far the fastest followed by a VBA Collection, followed by Cells and the Range object came in last.  So how can this be?  At the surface this might seem counterintuitive but if you think about it you realize that the Cells collection and Ranges are cross sections of all the cells on a worksheet (17,179,869,184) cells. The Cells collection is fairly simple because all the cells in are part of the same cell block.  The Cells just resolve the parent, create a new cells collection and return the reference.  The Range is considerably more complex because it supports multi-areas and I believe that is why it performed so much slower. Both the Dictionary and the VBA collection are less complicated.  You give them an address and they go straight to the stored Cell reference.  They don't have to go around checking the neighbors to see if they are going to be included in the block party.

### Cell, Cells, and Range Definition

[MSDN - Cell Objec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221403(v=office.11).aspx)

> Represents a single table cell. The Cell object is a member of the Cells collection. The Cells collection represents all the cells in the specified object.

[MSDN - Cells Collection Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221405(v=office.11).aspx)

> Use the Cells property to return the Cells collection.

[MSDN - Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel)

> Represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range.

```
Option Explicit

'
' COPYRIGHT ? DECISION MODELS LIMITED 2006. All rights reserved
' May be redistributed for free but
' may not be sold without the author's explicit permission.
'
Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" Alias _
                                      "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias _
                                      "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long

Private Const sCPURegKey = "HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0"
Private Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE As Long = &H80000002
Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegOpenKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, phkResult As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpType As Long, lpData As Any, lpcbData As Long) As Long

Public Enum ReturnTypes
    retDictionaryTime
    retVBACollection
    retCellsRefTime
    retRangeRefTime
End Enum

Function MicroTimer() As Double
'
' returns seconds
'
    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency
    '
    MicroTimer = 0
    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency  ' get ticks/sec
    getTickCount cyTicks1                             ' get ticks
    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency    ' calc seconds

End Function

Sub RangeLookupTimer(ReturnType As ReturnTypes)
    Const CELL_COUNT As Long = 1000
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim n As Long, repeats As Long, Result1 As Double, TimeOf As Double
    Dim dic As Object
    TimeOf = MicroTimer

    If ReturnType = retDictionaryTime Then
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(CELL_COUNT)
            Set dic(cell.Address(0, 0)) = cell
        Next
        For repeats = 1 To 1000
            For n = 1 To CELL_COUNT
                Call TypeName(dic("A" & n))
            Next
        Next
    ElseIf ReturnType = retCellsRefTime Then
        For repeats = 1 To 1000
            For n = 1 To CELL_COUNT
                Call TypeName(Sheet1.Cells(n, "A"))
            Next
        Next
    ElseIf ReturnType = retRangeRefTime Then
        For repeats = 1 To 1000
            For n = 1 To CELL_COUNT
                Call TypeName(Sheet1.Range("A" & n))
            Next
        Next
    ElseIf ReturnType = retVBACollection Then
        Dim colCells As New Collection
        For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(CELL_COUNT)
            colCells.Add Item:=cell, Key:=cell.Address(0, 0)
        Next
        For repeats = 1 To 1000
            For n = 1 To CELL_COUNT
                Call TypeName(colCells("A" & n))
            Next
        Next
    End If

    Result1 = MicroTimer - TimeOf
    Debug.Print Round(Result1, 2)
End Sub
```